# Encerrar a execução de um script após determinado tempo - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou implementando uma função que processa pacotes de rede. No momento estou usando um loop while para que a função sempre fique em execução, porém gostaria de determinar um tempo em ms e ao final desse tempo o loop se encerra. Podem me dar uma dica ? Um pedaço do meu loop até agora:

```py
    while True:
               
        status = pcap.loop(pd, 0, processing_pkts,
            ct.cast(ct.pointer(packet_count), ct.POINTER(ct.c_ubyte)))
        if status < 0:
            break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coloquei o timedelta em **segundos** para o exemplo, mas você tem as opções que você quiser somar
(weeks, days, hours, minutes, seconds, microseconds, milliseconds)
basta alterar no código o parametro dentro do timedelta.

```
from datetime import timedelta, datetime
end_time = datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds=10)
while True:
    # do something
    # ...

    if datetime.now() > end_time:
        break
```